# Make models in admin site appear only in debug mode otherwise display one model

Tags: python, django

I want to make my models appear in admin site only when debug variable is set to True, when debug is set to False I only want to display one model

I am looking for an elegant way to implement this

I thought I could do something like this:

```
if not DEBUG:
   admin.site._registry = {}
   admin.site.register(Model 1)
```

But where does this code should live? I want it to execute after execution of all admin.py modules from all applications where models registration takes place.

To sum it up

DEBUG = TRUE
Admin site shows:

- Model 1
- Model 2
- Model 3

DEBUG = FALSE
Admin site shows:

- Model 1

Comment: What is not working with this approach?

Comment: I don't know where this code should be placed. When I put it in settings module I get error AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")

Comment: You should do that in the `app_name/admins.py`.

Comment: I will have to do that in every single app. I want to write it only one time. Preferably in a module that is executed after all admin.py modules in my project

Comment: it is one extra line per `admins.py`, and it also is more the *Zen of Python* that *explicit is better than implicit*.

Answer (score 0):

You can override one of the `ready` methods of an `AppConfig` of any app. For example if you have an app named *`app_name`*, we can implement an `AppConfig` that looks like:

```
# app_name/apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig

class AppNameConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'app_name'

    def ready(self):
        from app_name.models import SomeModel
        from django.conf import settings
        if not settings.DEBUG:
            from django.contrib import admin
            for cls in list(admin.site._registry):
                if cls is not SomeName:
                    admin.site.unregister(cls)
        return super().ready()
```

with the *`SomeModel`* the model you wish to retain.